# Aws ELB status issue

Tags: xml, web, jpeg

I am new in this portal, I need help regarding aws elb creation.

when i crated elb in status or instance tab of elb it showing error this"instance has failed at least the unhealthy threshold number of health checks consecutively".

Can some one help this it's high parity.

Thanks to all

Bheema.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the page returns a 200 response, it should eventually pass the health check. The Health Check configuration includes the number of times a Health Check needs to return a good result and how often to check it. So, a Healthy count of 5 with a check every 30 seconds would take 2.5 minutes to return as Healthy.

If the HTTP health check is failing, try it with a TCP health check on port 8080 or 80 as per your configured web server.

Also, just in case, check that your VPC configuration allows a connection from the Load Balancer to the EC2 instance. This will be automatic if they are in the same Subnet, but Network ACLs can impact a connection between different Subnets.

Answer (score 0):

There might be no backend instances associated with the elb.